# Git installed but still gets "command not found"

Tags: git

I am working on a remote ubuntu server.

When I run `git which`, nothing happens. And when I run `git --version`, nothing happens either. Which would suggest that git is not installed on the server.

Yet, when I try to install git with `apt install git`, the response is

```
git is already the newest version (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3.10).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am very confused...

Comment: What is the result of `which git`?

Comment: No result. Nothing shows up.

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove git && sudo apt install git`

Comment: This worked! Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your git installation was corrupted.
Remove and reinstall git with:

```
sudo apt remove git && sudo apt install git
```